# Perl WWW::Mechanize Instagram

Tags: perl, instagram

Is it possible to use WWW::Mechanize in Perl code to login on Instagram? When I load the login form under https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher my code shows an error that it cannot find the login form.

```
my $browser;
my $res;
my $url;

my $username;
my $password;
my @formlist;

$username = "aaa";
$password = "bbb";

$browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher";
$browser->get($url);

$browser->form_number(1);
$browser->field("username", $username);
$browser->field("password", $password);
$browser->click();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `WWW::Mechanize` can only deal with vanilla HTML. It can not deal with Javascript. You need a headless browser like `WWW::Mechanize::Chrome`. Instagram offers an [API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) though, you're probably better of using that if it can do what you need.